# What is the best free software for converting photos to maps?

Tags: uv

[image]What is the best free software for converting photos to maps?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more or create an image representing what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Your question should directly relate to using Blender.  Currently it does not.   Therefore your new friends at BSE may close your question.  They do it because they care about you.  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free online Normal map generator: http://cpetry.github.io/NormalMap-Online/
Generate Maps from Textures and 3D models: https://shadermap.com/home/
Create Bump maps easily: https://www.crazybump.com/

Hope this meets your requirement! :)

Comment: Note though that ShaderMap watermarks maps in free version.